# Discord.js localisation works for command names, description and choices but not for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, localization

I'd like to translate my slash commands. `setNameLocalizations()` and `setDescriptionLocalizations` work as expected. If I add a string option with choices, using `name_localizations` also works; the choices on discord are localised.

However, if I want to translate autocompleted values, it only shows the English version (ie the `name` field). The docs state that `interaction.respond()` accepts an array of [`ApplicationCommandOptionChoiceData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ApplicationCommandOptionChoiceData) that has a `nameLocalizations` key but it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to translate these?

```js
export const command = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('example')
    .setDescription('Some description')
    .setNameLocalizations({ de: 'Beispiel' })
    .setDescriptionLocalizations({ de: 'Einige Beschreibung' })
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('month')
        .setDescription('Month')
        .setNameLocalizations({ de: 'monat' })
        .setDescriptionLocalizations({ de: 'Monat' })
        .addChoices(
          {
            name: 'January',
            name_localizations: { de: 'Januar' },
            value: '01',
          },
          {
            name: 'February',
            name_localizations: { de: 'Februar' },
            value: '02',
          },
          {
            name: 'March',
            name_localizations: { de: 'März' },
            value: '03',
          },
          // ... and so on
        )
        .setRequired(true),
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('gift')
        .setNameLocalizations({ de: 'Geschenk' })
        .setDescription('What gift you want?')
        .setDescriptionLocalizations({ de: 'Welches Geschenk willst du?' })
        .setAutocomplete(true)
        .setRequired(true),
    ),
  async autocomplete(interaction) {
    const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
    const filtered = values.filter((choice) =>
      choice.name.en.toLowerCase().includes(focusedValue.toLowerCase()),
    );
    await interaction.respond(
      filtered
        .map((choice) => ({
          name: choice.name.en,
          // it's completely ignored
          nameLocalizations: {
            de: choice.name.de,
          },
          value: choice.value,
        }))
        .slice(0, 25),
    );
  },
  // ... execute
};
```